# Switching background on page load with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, image, background

I have a finished working bootstrap 4 website that is an image gallery. It works fine. However, never one to leave well alone, I want to randomly change the jumbotron image when the home page is loaded with one of 6 images made for that purpose.

The javascript I am using is not working for the jumbotron. To sort out the issue, I have created a simple html page with no cdn's or jquery links. Just pure html and css with an in-page script tag.

I can easily switch the plain 'ol image file in the image tag. That works great. But to switch a background image in the section div which has a background set in CSS is not working.

I have tried all sorts of variations with the DOM switch but nothing works.

I have 3 questions:

1/ Can someone please let me know what the javascript (not jQuery) syntax is for that.

The CSS stipulates a background, not a background-image or backgroundImage, with a URL, not src as does the img tag. So I am assuming that the javascript would use = url(the path to the image).

But I may be wrong or I may be missing a set of brackets or something.

Since the CSS uses a relative path, I am assuming that the javascript would do the same. Adding in the root folder does not seem to accomplish anything, but that may be the rest of the DOM switch syntax causing the problem.

2/ I am using an onLoad in the body tag to call the javascript. Is this best practice or should I be using an event listener in the javascript file looking out for the completed page load.

3/ Is there a better way to implement the image switch?  I'm not looking for anything fancy, but just want to make sure that I'm using a common procedure.

My html, which includes all the CSS and javascript is as follows:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <style>
#header {
    background: url("images/header02.jpg") center center no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
 </style>
 </head>

 <body onLoad="myHeaderFunction()">

<img id="myImg" src="images/header05.jpg" width="900" height="200" alt="test image">

<section id="header"> </section>

<script>
    function myHeaderFunction() {
        var myImageArray = ["header01.jpg", "header02.jpg", "header03.jpg", "header04.jpg", "header05.jpg"];
        var item = myImageArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myImageArray.length)];
        var myPath = "images/" + item;
        document.getElementById("myImg").src = myPath;
        document.getElementById("header").style.background = myPath;
    }
</script>

 </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

should be

```
document.getElementById("header").style.background = "url('" + myPath +"')";
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks to TheCoder963 as well. See, this is why front end is just as difficult as back end.

Comment: You're welcome. please accept the my answer also :) Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the backgroundImage in a proper format:

```
document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + path + "')";
```

check this link: [Style background Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_background.asp)